# Create database index with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, indexing, data-annotations

Say I have the following model:

```
[Table("Record")]
public class RecordModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Record Id")]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    public string IMEI { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to add an index to the `IMEI` column through using an attribute, data annotation, or something from the model?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to this link: [Creating Indexes via Data Annotations with Entity Framework 5.0](http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2012/08/18/creating-indexes-via-data-annotations-with-entity-framework-5-0/)
you should write some kind of extension code:

```
using System; 

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class IndexAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IndexAttribute(string name, bool unique = false)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.IsUnique = unique;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public bool IsUnique { get; private set; }
}
```

and the second class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class IndexInitializer<T> : IDatabaseInitializer<T> where T : DbContext
{
    private const string CreateIndexQueryTemplate = "CREATE {unique} INDEX {indexName} ON {tableName} ({columnName})";

    public void InitializeDatabase(T context)
    {
        const BindingFlags PublicInstance = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

        foreach (var dataSetProperty in typeof(T).GetProperties(PublicInstance).Where(
            p => p.PropertyType.Name == typeof(DbSet<>).Name))
        {
            var entityType = dataSetProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Single();

            TableAttribute[] tableAttributes = (TableAttribute[])entityType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false);

            foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties(PublicInstance))
            {
                IndexAttribute[] indexAttributes = (IndexAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IndexAttribute), false);
                NotMappedAttribute[] notMappedAttributes = (NotMappedAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotMappedAttribute), false);
                if (indexAttributes.Length > 0 && notMappedAttributes.Length == 0)
                {
                    ColumnAttribute[] columnAttributes = (ColumnAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), false);

                    foreach (var indexAttribute in indexAttributes)
                    {
                        string indexName = indexAttribute.Name;
                        string tableName = tableAttributes.Length != 0 ? tableAttributes[0].Name : dataSetProperty.Name;
                        string columnName = columnAttributes.Length != 0 ? columnAttributes[0].Name : property.Name;
                        string query = CreateIndexQueryTemplate.Replace("{indexName}", indexName)
                            .Replace("{tableName}", tableName)
                            .Replace("{columnName}", columnName)
                            .Replace("{unique}", indexAttribute.IsUnique ? "UNIQUE" : string.Empty);

                        context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

                        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After it you can use your `index` this way:

```
[Required]
[Index("IMEIIndex", unique: true)]
[StringLength(15)]
public string IMEI { get; set; }
```

Comment: What do you have to be using to be able to use `Index`?  If I try to use this `[Index("IMEIIndex", unique: true)]` it asks me to generate my own Index class

Comment: Very nice, seems to have done the trick for me.  Thanks!  I'll give you the bounty when this site lets me (I have to wait 1 hour apparently)

Comment: upvote done! - one thing you forgot from that site (wasn't obvious as it was in a link) but you have to include `Database.SetInitializer(new IndexInitializer<DbContext>());` in your `OnModelCreating` of the dbcontext

Comment: @Pete - ok! Now it is save here in comments )

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adding the Index in the seeding method but I like this way better so I'll probably do this from now on as it just seems a bit neater - allows you to see the index on your model rather than having to look through your seeding methods too

Answer (score 20):

#### EF Core 5

In EF Core 5, the `Index` attribute should be placed on the class.
See: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations)

```
[Index(nameof(Url))]
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishedOn { get; set; }
}
```

or revert to the fluent syntax for more advanced option:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasIndex(p => p.Url)
        .IncludeProperties(
            p => new { p.Title, p.PublishedOn });
}
```

---

#### EF 6.1

Since the release of EF 6.1. (March 17th, 2014) there is indeed an `[Index]` attribute available.

Functionality as:

```
[Index("IMEIIndex", IsUnique = true)]
public string IMEI { get; set; }
```

comes out of the box.

PS: other properties are `Order` and `IsClustered`.

---

According to this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/02/11/ef-6-1-0-beta-1-available.aspx

It will be available in EF 6.1 as a standard DataAnnotation attribute.

> IndexAttribute allows indexes to be specified by placing an [Index] attribute on a property (or properties) in your Code First model. Code First will then create a corresponding index in the database.

Comment: Thanks. Just a note: you need to add an EntityFramework reference in the project where you want to use this. A System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is not enough. Took a bit for me to figure out.

Comment: To be fair, the current state of EF 6.x has "IsUnique = true/false" as second parameter.