# Unique Index using Data Annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, indexing, data-annotations

Is there a way to define a Unique Index using Data Annotations?

lets say I have a class:

```
public class User 
{
   [Key]
   public int UserID { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

If I want Email to be unique, how do I go about adding a Unique Index to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is near the same question I have already answered [MVC Model - create db index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17669769/502950)

According to this link: [Creating Indexes via Data Annotations with Entity Framework 5.0](http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2012/08/18/creating-indexes-via-data-annotations-with-entity-framework-5-0/)
you should write some kind of extension code:

```
using System; 

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class IndexAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IndexAttribute(string name, bool unique = false)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.IsUnique = unique;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public bool IsUnique { get; private set; }
}
```

and the second class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class IndexInitializer<T> : IDatabaseInitializer<T> where T : DbContext
{
    private const string CreateIndexQueryTemplate = "CREATE {unique} INDEX {indexName} ON {tableName} ({columnName})";

    public void InitializeDatabase(T context)
    {
        const BindingFlags PublicInstance = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

        foreach (var dataSetProperty in typeof(T).GetProperties(PublicInstance).Where(
            p => p.PropertyType.Name == typeof(DbSet<>).Name))
        {
            var entityType = dataSetProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Single();

            TableAttribute[] tableAttributes = (TableAttribute[])entityType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false);

            foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties(PublicInstance))
            {
                IndexAttribute[] indexAttributes = (IndexAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IndexAttribute), false);
                NotMappedAttribute[] notMappedAttributes = (NotMappedAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotMappedAttribute), false);
                if (indexAttributes.Length > 0 && notMappedAttributes.Length == 0)
                {
                    ColumnAttribute[] columnAttributes = (ColumnAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), false);

                    foreach (var indexAttribute in indexAttributes)
                    {
                        string indexName = indexAttribute.Name;
                        string tableName = tableAttributes.Length != 0 ? tableAttributes[0].Name : dataSetProperty.Name;
                        string columnName = columnAttributes.Length != 0 ? columnAttributes[0].Name : property.Name;
                        string query = CreateIndexQueryTemplate.Replace("{indexName}", indexName)
                            .Replace("{tableName}", tableName)
                            .Replace("{columnName}", columnName)
                            .Replace("{unique}", indexAttribute.IsUnique ? "UNIQUE" : string.Empty);

                        context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

                        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After it you can use your `index` this way:

```
[Required]
[Index("IMEIIndex", unique: true)]
[StringLength(15)]
public string IMEI { get; set; }
```

Comment: You should mark this question as duplicate in stead of repeating an answer.

Comment: @GertArnold - done it - marked

Comment: Thanks. But I think you should also have deleted this answer. Redundant content is a problem because content can be edited (= improved) all the time. If you're interested in the rep (who isn't?), people who feel helped by this answer would probably have upvoted the other answer in stead when redirected to it. And there are all kinds of shiny badges to be earned for answers with high votes! - Well, just a comment. Two good answers is still better than one poor answer :)

Comment: @GertArnold - I wasnt sure that it 100% the same question - thats why I have reposted my answer

Comment: @GertArnold - and I also dont know why moderators dont react to mark it as a dupplicate. I have flagged it already. Maybe you can flag it as dupplicate too - and than moderators will react =)

Comment: OK, done. It always takes some time, either to collect 5 close votes or for a moderator to close.