# Entity Framework Code First 6.0: is there any annotations to add index to a column(s)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, indexing

I'm using EF6 for first time. having a table like this:

```
public class DBBlog
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }  //<-- need to be indexed
}
```

please advice

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853909/mvc-model-create-db-index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no DataAnnotion yet in EF to create indices. When you're using migrations, then you can adjust the created migration to add an Index manually.

Answer (score 3):

The capability was added for EF 6.1 and is available already in nightly builds. For more information:

https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/57