# How to make SQL table property unique ( not repeatable)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

Im new in MVC and im using Microsoft Visual Studio. So I have a controller to insert data into my SQL table with 4 properties ID Name Broi and Cena.

```
[HttpPost]       
public ActionResult Table(ProductTable product)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(product);
  }
  using (var contex = new DefaultConnection())
  {
    contex.Products.Add(product);
     contex.SaveChanges();                    
  }
  return View();            
 }
```

This is my producttalbe class:

```
 [Table("ProductTable")]
 public class ProductTable
 {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Broi { get; set; }
    public int Cena { get; set; }
 }
```

But I want to make the Name property Unique so it will never repeat and if it repeats to call message in my View like "This Name already exists". I can see when making the table there is a property called "Not for replication" but I can't turn it to true it stays in gray and I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this attribute to your property:

```
[Unique(ErrorMessage="This Name already exists!")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

[here](http://binarysculpting.com/2012/01/16/mvc-validation-2-validating-for-column-uniqueness/) is how to implement the Unique attribute, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853909/mvc-model-create-db-index/17669769#17669769) is another extension code.

Comment: Sure, Here is a [link](http://binarysculpting.com/2012/01/14/mvc-validation-part-1-custom-unobtrusive-validation-using-attributes/) explaining validation in MVC 

N.B. There are three more parts listed after that part.

Comment: So you mean Unique is your custom attribute.

Comment: Nope, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(v=vs.100).aspx) is how to use data annotation attributes

Comment: I have an idea about how to use data annotation attributes, But I don't think Unique is a valid property. I think you need some Remote validation for that.

Comment: Yes you're right, [here](http://binarysculpting.com/2012/01/16/mvc-validation-2-validating-for-column-uniqueness/) is how to make a Unique attribute.

and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853909/mvc-model-create-db-index/17669769#17669769) is another extension code.

Comment: Add them to your answer.