# How do I include a complex type to an Entity Index?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have these 2 POCOs...

```
public class SqlTrace
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SqlTraceFile> TraceFiles { get; set; }
}

public class SqlTraceFile
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual SqlTrace Trace { get; set; }
}
```

I created a 1 to many relationship between the trace and its files. I want to add an index that would make it so that SqlTraceFiles are unique to its SqlTrace; Allow multiple SqlTraceFiles to be named the same as long as they belong to a different SqlTrace.

Below is what I have within the SqlTraceFileConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration< SqlTraceFile >

```
Property(TraceFile => TraceFile.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(
                new IndexAttribute("IX_SQLTracefile_FileTrace", 1) { IsUnique = true }
                ));
Property(TraceFile => TraceFile.Trace)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(
                new IndexAttribute("IX_SQLTracefile_FileTrace", 1) { IsUnique = true }
                ));
```

My problem is that it doesn't take the 'tracefile => tracefile.trace' I am guessing that entity want the foreign key in place of 'tracefile.trace'. Is there a pattern I must follow to accomplish this? Or a workaround to my position.

Comment: You can create indexes with an attribute as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853909/create-database-index-with-entity-framework/21743868#21743868

Comment: You can put the index on an explicitly created FK property

Comment: There is no way of doing this using Fluent API and not the DataNotation?

Comment: I think fluent will also work, but I prefer annotations so I don't really know. It would be a good idea to create the FK-id explicit, so you can access it in your fluent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your poco's:

```
public class SqlTrace
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //added indexes with annotations
    [Index("otherNameIndex", IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //changed to ICollection
    public virtual ICollection<SqlTraceFile> TraceFiles { get; set; }
}

public class SqlTraceFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Index("nameIndex", IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //added the FK id property explicit and put an index on to it.
    [Index("indexname", IsUnique = true)]
    public int SqlTraceId {get;set;}
    public virtual SqlTrace Trace { get; set; }
}
```

You won't need the fluent code this way.

Comment: I accepted the answer... I was really hoping to get it done using FluentAPI. You did mention that I could explicitly add the foreign key, I didn't know you could do that. I think that is going to be my approach. Many thanks for the quick response and answer.

Comment: No prob, and if you find the fluent way; you can always post it as answer yourself. I am sure you'll get some upvotes :-)

Comment: @Hakubex: as a final remark: in this scenario the `SqlTraceId` is set as key for `SqlTrace` by naming convention (`SqlTrace` + `Id`). You can also pick an arbitrary name, but then you'll need the `[ForeignKey]` attribute.