# How do I include a complex type to an Entity Index?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have these 2 POCOs...

```
public class SqlTrace
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SqlTraceFile> TraceFiles { get; set; }
}

public class SqlTraceFile
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual SqlTrace Trace { get; set; }
}
```

I created a 1 to many relationship between the trace and its files. I want to add an index that would make it so that SqlTraceFiles are unique to its SqlTrace; Allow multiple SqlTraceFiles to be named the same as long as they belong to a different SqlTrace.

Below is what I have within the SqlTraceFileConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration< SqlTraceFile >

```
Property(TraceFile => TraceFile.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(
                    new IndexAttribute("IX_SQLTracefile_FileTrace", 1) { IsUnique = true }
                    ));
Property(TraceFile => TraceFile.Trace)
                .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(
                    new IndexAttribute("IX_SQLTracefile_FileTrace", 1) { IsUnique = true }
                    ));
```

My problem is that it doesn't take the 'tracefile => tracefile.trace' I am guessing that entity want the foreign key in place of 'tracefile.trace'. Is there a pattern I must follow to accomplish this? Or a workaround to my position.

Comment: @gnat ok, didn't know. now I know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include a complex type to an Entity Index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489396/how-do-i-include-a-complex-type-to-an-entity-index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your TraceFile poco add one more property `SqlTraceId` which will represent id for the foreign key and use that property to create index. So, on your navigation property add data annotation `[ForeignKey="SqlTraceId "]` and your unique index annotation place on the `Name` and `SqlTraceId` properties. Using data annotations you can achieve that using this example:

```
    public class SqlTraceFile
    {
      public int id { get; set; }
      [Index("IX_SQLTracefile_FileTrace", 1, IsUnique = true)]
      public string Name { get; set; }
      [Index("IX_SQLTracefile_FileTrace", 2, IsUnique = true)]
      public int SqlTraceId { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("SqlTraceId ")]
      public virtual SqlTrace Trace { get; set; }
   }
```

I think you can do the same using FluentAPI instead of data annotations, but the main thing is that you get idea how to solve this problem